# css flexbox image size strangely changing

Tags: css, image, flexbox

I started testing Flexbox using on an existing template from an older stackoverflow question
[image]

HTML

```css
.flex-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.kutu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="team ">
  <header class="exp">

  </header>
  <div class="flex-items">

    <div class="kutu">
      <h2>Temsilci</h2>

      <div>
        <img src="/images/ben.png" alt="">
        <h4>Umutcan <span class="text-primary">"ııııııııııııığ"</span> Adiguzel</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src="/images/kaan.png" alt="">
        <h4>Ahmet Kaan <span class="text-primary">"kargolar seffaf mi"</span> Aslan</h4>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="kutu">
      <h2>Bas kole</h2>

      <div>
        <img src="" alt="">
        <h4>Ismail Emre <span class="text-primary">"Emre"</span> Gunes</h4>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="kutu">
      <h2>Avusturya Temsilcisi</h2>

      <div>
        <img src="" alt="">
        <h4>Hayri Cem <span class="text-primary">"hayry"</span> Adiguzel</h4>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="kutu">
      <h2>Avcilar Yonetim Birligi Uyesi</h2>

      <div>
        <img src="" alt="">
        <h4>Mehmet Ali <span class="text-primary">"ali58"</span> Kuzu</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src="" alt="">
        <h4>Anil <span class="text-primary">"anil"</span> Akyil</h4>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="kutu">
      <h2>Eskortlar Odasi Esbaskan Vekili</h2>

      <div>
        <img src="/images/burak.png" alt="">
        <h4>Burak <span class="text-primary">"yarrak gurmesi ekmen"</span> Colakoglu</h4>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="kutu">
      <h2>Lezbiyen Haklari Koruma Birligi Uyesi</h2>

      <div>
        <img src="" alt="">
        <h4>Ugur <span class="text-primary">"bardo"</span> Yengil</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src="/images/cenker.png" alt="">
        <h4>Cenker <span class="text-primary">"ceko anılelifbarışsınoğulları31"</span> Goksu</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src="/images/canemir.png" alt="">
        <h4>Canemir <span class="text-primary">"Gay Emir"</span> Ozdemir</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src="/images/denizbora.png" alt="">
        <h4>Deniz Bora <span class="text-primary">"dbe"</span> Ekiz</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src="/images/kutay.png" alt="">
        <h4>Mehmet Kutay <span class="text-primary">"kutii"</span> Keklik</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src="/images/gokdeniz.png" alt="">
        <h4>gokdeniz <span class="text-primary">"anıllaelifevlensin"</span> Dincer</h4>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="kutu">
      <h2>Kaymakam Kalem Muduru</h2>

      <div>
        <img src="/images/ilker.png" alt="">
        <h4>Ilker <span class="text-primary">"aktif gay"</span> Tari</h4>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="kutu">
      <h2>Muhtarlar</h2>

      <div>
        <img src="" alt="">
        <h4>Muhammed Can <span class="text-primary">"s2m2m7"</span> Adiguzel</h4>`enter code here`
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src="" alt="">
        <h4>Metehan <span class="text-primary">"Its mother fucking ghost"</span> Adiguzel</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src="" alt="">
        <h4>Enes <span class="text-primary">"Suprise"</span> Adiguzel</h4>
      </div>

    </div>









  </div>
</section>
```

CSS flexbox image size strangely changing I would be grateful if you could help

Comment: By _image size strangely changing_, do you mean the images are inconsistent in their width & height? There can be a variety of factors there—e.g. source image dimensions and aspect ratio, `flex` property, other content items inside the flex items, etc. I'd suggest you check out https://flexboxfroggy.com/ and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ to cover the fundamentals of flex layouts, which might help solve your challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand, if you don't want that the size change, put a fixed width and height, for example, width: 50% height:50% in the images. This may occurs because each image has a different size. I would recomend also put a fix width in the h4 or in the div that contains both.

```css
        .flex-items {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          text-align: center;
          height: 100%;
        }
        
        .kutu {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          text-align: center;
          width: 100%;
        }
    
        img { 
        width: 20%;
        height: 20%;}

       .kutu div { width: 40%;}
```